# MySQL chat table, join user names?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a simple chat database like this:

```
id | from | to | message
---|------|----|-----------------
1  | 1    | 2  | hello
2  | 1    | 2  | are you there?
3  | 2    | 1  | yes I'm here!
```

Also there is a second table that holds the names

```
`users`.`firstname` and `users`.`lastname`
```

I'm trying to combine the two, so when retrieving the chats, I'd also have the names of both participants. My query looks like this right now:

```
SELECT 
  `messages`.*, 
  CONCAT(`users`.`firstname`, " ", `users`.`lastname`) as `nameFrom`     
FROM `messages`     
  INNER JOIN 
     `users` ON `messages`.`from` = `users`.`id`
```

It works fine, but if I try to add another join, just change `messages`.`from` to `messages`.`to` I get errors.

How do I combine the first name & last name of each participant when retrieving the chat log?

Thanks

Comment: Second table sorry I'll edit that bit ;)

Comment: no need to, you already have given hints :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to get both the sender and receiver?  If so, this should work joining the Users table twice:

```
SELECT 
  `messages`.*, 
  CONCAT(u.`firstname`, " ", u.`lastname`) as `nameFrom`,
  CONCAT(u2.`firstname`, " ", u2.`lastname`) as `nameTo`
FROM `messages`     
  INNER JOIN 
     `users` u ON `messages`.`from` = u.`id`
  INNER JOIN 
     `users` u2 ON `messages`.`to` = u2.`id`
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to basically join the table `users` twice on table `messages` provided that you supply an `ALIAS` to uniquely identify the tables with the same table name.

```
SELECT  messages.*, 
        CONCAT(a.firstname, ' ', a.lastname) as nameFrom,
        CONCAT(b.firstname, ' ', b.lastname) as nameTo  
FROM    messages     
        INNER JOIN users a
            ON messages.from = a.id
        INNER JOIN users b
            ON messages.to = b.id
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/619d9/1)